# How to use if statment in UNIX

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I was trying to execute the following commands.

```
de="hello world"
if [ $de -eq "hi" ]; then
....
....
```

because of the space between hello and the world, it out put an error. but if I define de="helloworld" it works fine. can you please tell me if there is a way I can use if statement with sentences that have spaces in it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quote the variable name,

```
de="hello world"
if [ "$de" = "hi" ]; then
```

`-eq` is for comparing numbers, so use = for text. See [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-bash-test.html) for a nice overview on how to do various comparisions in bash.